# How to avoid hissing sound in the end of silent WAV file generated by TTS.synthesizetofile

Tags: text-to-speech, wav, noise, google-text-to-speech, silent

I am using TTS.synthesizetofile() to generate a silent wav file for my project!

The text played is series of ssml code with break inserted by following tags:

```
<speak version="1.1" ><break time="1500ms" /></speak>
```

However, the generated files have a very feeble hissing sound in the end of generated wav file.

Any idea on how to avoid it would be really helpful!

Comment: First I would verify that there truly is a distortion at the end of the wav file by opening it in audacity (for example) and looking at it.  It could actually not be in the fille and happening for some other reason

Comment: yes i checked and there is a distortion in the end.